# Why are my activities being stopped?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have "inherited" an app from another employee, and now I have to make some modifications. And for some reason whenever I start an activity the previous one is stopped instead of being paused. I have looked at [THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16442933/1688731), but while my app is a barcode scanner app (that uses the camera) there are no other similarities. I am moving between the launcher activity and other non-camera related activities and the launcher activity is being stopped. And it's not due to   `android:launchMode="singleTask"` because I have commented that line from the manifest.

The reason for needing a paused launcher activity, not a stopped one, is that I intend to implement a public static ArrayList to which I will add objects from other activities.

Does anyone have any ideas to why this is happening? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: *is that I intend to implement a public static ArrayList to which I will add objects from other activities.* - you shouldn't do this.

Comment: You cannot rely on an Activity not being destroyed.  You should read about the Activity life cycle and code appropriately.  As Luksprog says, your plan is a really really bad idea.

Comment: The reason I want to do that is that the objects I will add to the public static ArrayList are from different instances of a recursive activity. Not sure how to gather them all into one place. In any case the always-stopping-launcher activity is abnormal.

Comment: What do you  mean `is abnormal`?

Comment: @Simon, I mean that I've never seen launcher activities stopping immediately after I start another simple one.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, in low-memory conditions there have been reports that the Android OS straight-up unloads the class that represents your activity. That means that any static variable in that class will get removed from memory. The next time you have an instance of your Activity, the static var will not be null, but it will be empty. I had a similar issue with singletons just disappearing after some time (the issue was actually irresponsible memory usage, but still - don't rely on static objects to persist data)

Just serialize your objects and persist them, or serialize parts of their data and use that to create new objects whenever you need them.

Answer (score 1):

It is the normal behavior. An activity is paused only as long as it is visible, that is when a dialog is displayed or another activity which has transparent background. Instead when you launch a new Activity, if the previous one is not visible anymore, it enters the stopped state. This is the most common behavior possible!

If you need to run a background service, that is, something that lasts across different activities, then you should use a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your activity has been killed due to the high memory usage (camera, barcode scanning, analyzing the scanned image, etc).

You can extend the Application class and implement your public static ArrayList in the extended Application class. You can find a lot of example how to extend the Application class.

Comment: There is almost no memory usage. I start the app with the simple launcher activity, then I press comments and it opens another activity with a edittext field and a Done button, and in that instance the launcher activity stops.

Comment: How do you start the second activity etc. paste some code here.

Comment: That is strange, i thought you start the barcode scanning activity..., anyway extending the Application class and putting there the ArrayList will resolve your non-persistent data storing problems.

Comment: `bOverview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
     {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v)
       {
        refreshNumbers();
        startActivity(new Intent(ProductionActivity.this, OverviewActivity.class));

       }
     });`

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29):

```
protected void onPause ()
```

Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is going into the background, but has not (yet) been killed. The counterpart to onResume().

When activity B is launched in front of activity A, this callback will be invoked on A. B will not be created until A's onPause() returns, so be sure to not do anything lengthy here.

This callback is mostly used for saving any persistent state the activity is editing, to present a "edit in place" model to the user and making sure nothing is lost if there are not enough resources to start the new activity without first killing this one. This is also a good place to do things like stop animations and other things that consume a noticeable amount of CPU in order to make the switch to the next activity as fast as possible, or to close resources that are exclusive access such as the camera.

**In situations where the system needs more memory it may kill paused processes to reclaim resources. Because of this, you should be sure that all of your state is saved by the time you return from this function. In general onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is used to save per-instance state in the activity and this method is used to store global persistent data (in content providers, files, etc.)**

**After receiving this call you will usually receive a following call to onStop() (after the next activity has been resumed and displayed), however in some cases there will be a direct call back to onResume() without going through the stopped state.**

*Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.*